# Map model class to render view parameters with Glass.View v4?

Tags: glass-mapper

I have a project with Glass.Mapper v4 and i have a simple model class like this:

```
    public class Separator
    {
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual string CssColorClass { get; set; }
    }
```

And a razor view like this:

```
@model ConexioFC.Models.Separator

This is the separator
<h2 class="@Model.CssColorClass">@Model.Title</h2>
```

From Sitecore i have this templates:

[image]

Then i have a View Rendering like this:
This view rendering has a parameters template pointing to the template previously shown.
[image]

Then i have on the control properties of the page:

[image]

The problem is that when i go to the page preview the `Model.CssColorClass` and `Model.Title` are blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all is not recommended to put content like Title in the rendering paramenters.

```
@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<ConexioFC.Models.Separator>

var parameters = GetRenderingParameters<ConexioFC.Models.RenderingParameters.Separator>();}
```

and you can to access parameters using @parameters.PropertyName

More informations you can find here:
http://www.glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial23

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714169/inherit-model-and-rendering-parameters-both-in-sitecore-mvc-view-using-glass-map

Comment: What would be the `NameofyourParametersTemplate`?

Comment: The template that contains your rendering parameters

Comment: So this is the best approach to use with Glass.Mapper v4? because i though that this was for Glass.Mapper v3.x and with Glass.Mapper v4 was more easy to do (without using the `GetRenderingParameters`) like here http://www.glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial2.

Comment: Link you send me now : is not for rendering params is for sitecore fields

Answer (score 0):

That's because your rendering parameters aren't your viewmodel, the page item/datasource item is.

You can however get it as a viewmodel if you want, have a look at this blog post:
https://visionsincode.wordpress.com/2016/08/26/map-your-rendering-parameters-to-your-glass-mapper-viewmodels-in-sitecore/

Or the default way of working with rendering parameters:
http://www.glass.lu/mapper/sc/tutorials/tutorial23

```
@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<ConexioFC.Models.Separator>

@{ var parameters = GetRenderingParameters<ConexioFC.Models.RenderingParameters.Separator>();}
```